# Votes after maximum reputation limit

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, search

As the daily maximum reputation limit is 200 what will happen if I receive a vote after the daily maximum limit?

Is it added in the next day or those votes remain unaffected.?

Can somebody explain?

Comment: The votes don't give you reputation beyond the cap. You will not get the reputation the next day.

Comment: Only bounties (+bounty amount), deletion refund (varies), accepted edits (+2 per if eligible), and accepted answers (+15 per) can get you above 200.